# AmCharts 4 - column's bullet/babel position

Tags: amcharts4

everyone

So, I'm having some trouble with AmCharts 4 again.

Is there any way to always show the column's bullet/label?
[My case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWREg.png)

We can use this example, from AmCharts documentation, to reproduce my situation. Just set labelBullet.label.dy to 20 positive.

`labelBullet.label.dy = 20;`

https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/VxbVeq

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set [`maskBullets`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/xychart/#maskBullets_property) to false on the chart instance to prevent it from clipping the LabelBullet, e.g. `chart.maskBullets = false;`

Demo:

```js
// Create chart instance
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);

// Add data
chart.data = [{
  "date": new Date(2018, 3, 20),
  "value": 90
}, {
  "date": new Date(2018, 3, 21),
  "value": 102
}, {
  "date": new Date(2018, 3, 22),
  "value": 65
}, {
  "date": new Date(2018, 3, 23),
  "value": 62
}, {
  "date": new Date(2018, 3, 24),
  "value": 55
}, {
  "date": new Date(2018, 3, 25),
  "value": 81
}];

chart.maskBullets = false;
// Create axes
var dateAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());

// Create value axis
var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());

// Create series
var lineSeries = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
lineSeries.dataFields.valueY = "value";
lineSeries.dataFields.dateX = "date";
lineSeries.name = "Sales";
lineSeries.strokeWidth = 3;

// Add simple bullet
var circleBullet = lineSeries.bullets.push(new am4charts.CircleBullet());
circleBullet.circle.stroke = am4core.color("#fff");
circleBullet.circle.strokeWidth = 2;

var labelBullet = lineSeries.bullets.push(new am4charts.LabelBullet());
labelBullet.label.text = "{value}";
labelBullet.label.dy = 20;
```

```html
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv" style="width: 100%; height: 300px;"></div>
```